# Is there a way to get more than 50 results from maxResults with the Youtube API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get a list of my subscribers using the Subscriptions: list. Is there a way to get values for all of my subscribers, or is it only possible to get 50 max?  Is there another way to get values for all of my subscribers? I am aware the documentation says you can only get 50 results max, but I wanted to see if there was another way to get all the values.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The max results you can get with 1 call is 50.
To get more results, you would need to make multiple calls. After the first call finishes and there are more results that can be obtained, the API call should return a string for the `nextPageToken` property. Use this for the optional `pageToken` parameter for your next API call. Repeat this process until you've obtained all the results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Take a look at the pageToken parameter listed in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list):

The relevant description is:

```
The pageToken parameter identifies a specific page in the result set that should be 
returned. In an API response, the nextPageToken and prevPageToken properties identify 
other pages that could be retrieved.
```